# In-memory Java database that I can persist (as a single huge blob of memory)

Tags: java, database, memory-management, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am looking for an in-memory relational (SQL) database for Java (something like HSQLDB), whose whole state I can serialise.

```
wholeDatabase.serialize(outputStream);
newCopyOftheDatabase.loadFrom(inputStream);
```

Or maybe the DB only uses a byte[] that I give it on initialization:

```
byte[] memory = new byte[10 *1024*1024];
new InMemoryDatabase(memory);
```

The database will not be too huge, low tens of MB, but I cannot write files, so I need to stream everything off the machine before I shut the VM down (and periodically for backup).

I could use plain (and easily serializable) Java data structures like arrays or maps instead of a DB, but I want to be able to use SQL.

Comment: I get the feeling that writing to a ramdisk and having the OS back 'that' up might be a bit more workable, rather than trying to do it all in you application.

Comment: http://www.h2database.com has a slew a features. Might be worth sending an email to the author...

Answer (score 6):

HSQLDB has an in-memory option:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:aname", "sa", "");
```

You just need to dump and restore the contents. To dump the structure, you may use the `SCRIPT` SQL command. Than you can dump every table by select. There may be a better API used by the manager and/or server internally, but you need to have a look at the (open) sources for this, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of patching HSQLDB?

http://hsqldb.svn.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JavaDB will support this soon:

http://blogs.oracle.com/kah/entry/derby_10_5_preview_in

Comment: That blog post doesn't exactly demonstrate piping the database contents to a single stream.